# iOS - Access user's location when location permission is denied

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location

I want to get the user's location even when he/she has denied location access in app permissions. I have tried using this :- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Is there any other way to do this ? Also, is it possible that the build may get rejected by App Store if we try and get the user's loc even when he has denied it.